# How to [recursively] Zip a directory in PHP?

Tags: php, directory, zip, directory-structure, recursion

Directory is something like:

```
home/
    file1.html
    file2.html
Another_Dir/
    file8.html
    Sub_Dir/
        file19.html
```

I am using the same PHP Zip class used in PHPMyAdmin http://trac.seagullproject.org/browser/branches/0.6-bugfix/lib/other/Zip.php . I'm not sure how to zip a directory rather than just a file. Here's what I have so far:

```
$aFiles = $this->da->getDirTree($target);
/* $aFiles is something like, path => filetime
Array
(
    [home] => 
    [home/file1.html] => 1251280379
    [home/file2.html] => 1251280377
    etc...
)

*/
$zip = & new Zip();
foreach( $aFiles as $fileLocation => $time ){
    $file = $target . "/" . $fileLocation;
    if ( is_file($file) ){
        $buffer = file_get_contents($file);
        $zip->addFile($buffer, $fileLocation);
    }
}
THEN_SOME_PHP_CLASS::toDownloadData($zip); // this bit works ok
```

but when I try to unzip the corresponding downloaded zip file I get "operation not permitted"

This error only happens when I try to unzip on my mac, when I unzip through the command line the file unzips ok. Do I need to send a specific content type on download, currently 'application/zip'

Comment: This code does actually work - but for some reason you can't unzip it on Mac OS (unless you use CLI unzip). Zip file unstuffs ok on PC.

Comment: this can help you http://codingbin.com/compressing-a-directory-of-files-with-php/

Answer (score 272, accepted):

Here is a simple function that can compress any file or directory recursively, only needs the zip extension to be loaded.

```
function Zip($source, $destination)
{
    if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
        return false;
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
        return false;
    }

    $source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));

    if (is_dir($source) === true)
    {
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);

            // Ignore "." and ".." folders
            if( in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/')+1), array('.', '..')) )
                continue;

            $file = realpath($file);

            if (is_dir($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
            }
            else if (is_file($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
            }
        }
    }
    else if (is_file($source) === true)
    {
        $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
    }

    return $zip->close();
}
```

Call it like this:

```
Zip('/folder/to/compress/', './compressed.zip');
```

Comment: `Zip('/folder/to/compress/', './compressed.zip');`where should i put this?

Comment: Worked very well, my only question is that my script runs from a different location to the files to be zipped, therefore when I provide the 1st argument that full filepath location is used within the zip, like so: C:\wamp\www\export\pkg-1211.191011\pkg-1211.191011.zip, that full nested folder structure being inside the new archive. Is there a way to adapt the above script to only contain the files and directories I'm pointing at, and not the full path they come from?

Comment: @Danjah: I ported this from my framework (https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/) but only adapted it to *nix systems, the issue you mention doesn't exist in the framework because the paths are normalized. Try replacing all forward slashes (`/`) with two backward slashes (`\\\`) - that should solve your problem (in Windows) I think.

Comment: @Danjah: I've updated the code, should work for both *nix and Windows now.

Comment: Excellent tip, thank you, it was almost perfect. I had to leave the 'new directory' slash as fwd, otherwise WinZip complained about not being able to view the archive in "Explorer Mode" but in "All Files" mode instead... which still didn't quite display correctly. The archive was correct upon unpacking though. But with the single fwd slash it is a) relative to zipped files and b) fully explorable in Windows. Thanks Alix. EDIT: Code update, even better, thanks again :D

Comment: Sorry, edit time expired on my last comment, I still get the full path unfortunately...

Comment: @Alix: Bingo! Explorable, relative Zip archive - thanks very much!

Comment: I wonder why this is using `file_get_contents` and adding strings. doesn't zip support adding files directly?

Comment: @hakre: It does, but there are some bugs. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-addfile.php#74297 and the other comments, another workaround would be to close and reopen the Zip file every *n* files but the `file_get_contents()` looks cleaner to me (although it can give problems if you try to zip huge files).

Comment: while using this i had encountered a memory limit problem. replacing the addFromString with a addFile solved that issue.

Comment: @yossi: Yes, but read my comment to hakre - that may have problems too.

Comment: I get "Warning: the Zip file is read-only. A file name in the archive is invalid and had to be fixed:" when I use this?

Comment: Edit (past 5 min mark): Fixed by changing `$zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));` to `$zip->addFromString(basename($file), file_get_contents($file));` For some reason, `str_replace` was not erasing the `$source` from the file, so it was including the fill filepath in the zip.

Comment: @le_garry: Weird... But this answer has been edited beyond recognition. Would you mind trying this revision http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/993fbebb-3066-4188-99c6-c19a6537e8bf/view-source and telling me if you still have the same problem?

Comment: Alix, I think the problem was the extra "/" appended to $source. I removed it (using the revision you posted), and the zip turned out exactly how I wanted to. When the "/" was still there, the zip file would have a file structure all the way to the base root of the server. Cheers!

Comment: Is there a option to compress it on the fly? So the `zip` is not saved to the server. I've try to change some things and add the `Content-type` and `Content-Disposition` but then is the `zip` archive broken.

Comment: @GerritHoekstra: My code has changed beyond recognition, but how about you zip it to a temporary file? Wouldn't that work?

Comment: how can one use this code to iterate through two directories and have them in the same zip? I just want to backup my images folder i.e. `/images/upload/` and `/cms/images/users/`

Comment: @Alex: Look into the PharData class.

Comment: @winona you put it on your php script, preferrably on the same file where the function is defined.

Comment: Hi i tried this function and it zips my whole wamp directory up to my defined source. I've also tried all your revisions but it still does the same. BTW nice work!

Comment: Update i just removed all the realpath for it to work. Will that be a problem when i move my project in a linux environment?

Comment: Probably cleaner to add the `FileystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS` option to the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` call instead of searching for `'.'` and `'..'` manually.

Comment: You have to replace all `'/'` with `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` to make it work on Windows, of course. Otherwise, you'll end up with the full path (including drive name) in your ZIP, e.g. `C:\Users\...`.

Comment: sorry people.. i am using this script on a windows 2008 server and it is returning the fullpath into the zip file. i have tried changing '/' to DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR and also @le_garry solution and the old revision but none of them worked correctly.. the last two btw return me the fullpath with no files at the end of path, instead they are all in the root folder together at the parent of fullpath which is C:. Any ideas, this is quite annoying to browse 6 folders to reach the files

Comment: i resolved the issue i was having by changing all the '/' to '\\'

Comment: I love the function and it works great, however, when it makes the zip, it makes a huge line of folder starting at C:\ going through the Users folder and all the way down to the folder i wanted zipped which has all the files in it.

Comment: Nevermind all, the double back slash fixed it. my fault

Comment: The original code was/is broken and redundant. There's no need to replace `//` with `\ ` as this actually breaks the foreach on windows. If you use the built-in `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` as you should, there's no need to replace. The hardcoding of `/` is what was causing some users to have problems. I was confused for a bit as to why I was getting an empty archive. My revision will run fine under *nix and Windows.

Comment: This was working, except it was creating a folder structure rooted from the /root drive on my Windows machine. I altered it to fix the problem and use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead. [Here's the code.](http://pastebin.com/1dqbzAQx)

Comment: how can i give a array values to $source path.in array  multiple file paths are there.

Comment: Just a note for anyone else reading this. This recommendation uses will have memory usage issues when you are dealing with very large files. A better and MUCH cleaner solution can be found in this article http://ninad.pundaliks.in/blog/2011/05/recursively-zip-a-directory-with-php/

Comment: This script is pretty good. Wouldn't it be possible to `unset` any variable in the process so there is no `memory_limit` issue? I don't know if it's the iterator or the zip object that's taking all the memory, but unsetting it and setting it back to where it was at (so it remains incremential) could be a good upgrade.

Comment: @AlixAxel how can I add all files to a subdirectory of my zip archive?

Comment: terrible that in 2018 with PHP 7 we still have to jump through hoops... it's a 2 liner in python.. makes me want to switch

Comment: If you have large files using `file_get_contents` may cause php to run out of memory.

Comment: It's only necessary to use `addEmptyDir()` if you want to include empty directories in the zip file. Otherwise, `addFromString()` and `addfile()` will already create directories from the relative path.

Answer (score 25):

Yet another recursive directory tree archiving, implemented as an extension to ZipArchive. As a bonus, a single-statement tree compression helper function is included. Optional localname is supported, as in other ZipArchive functions. Error handling code to be added...

```
class ExtendedZip extends ZipArchive {

    // Member function to add a whole file system subtree to the archive
    public function addTree($dirname, $localname = '') {
        if ($localname)
            $this->addEmptyDir($localname);
        $this->_addTree($dirname, $localname);
    }

    // Internal function, to recurse
    protected function _addTree($dirname, $localname) {
        $dir = opendir($dirname);
        while ($filename = readdir($dir)) {
            // Discard . and ..
            if ($filename == '.' || $filename == '..')
                continue;

            // Proceed according to type
            $path = $dirname . '/' . $filename;
            $localpath = $localname ? ($localname . '/' . $filename) : $filename;
            if (is_dir($path)) {
                // Directory: add & recurse
                $this->addEmptyDir($localpath);
                $this->_addTree($path, $localpath);
            }
            else if (is_file($path)) {
                // File: just add
                $this->addFile($path, $localpath);
            }
        }
        closedir($dir);
    }

    // Helper function
    public static function zipTree($dirname, $zipFilename, $flags = 0, $localname = '') {
        $zip = new self();
        $zip->open($zipFilename, $flags);
        $zip->addTree($dirname, $localname);
        $zip->close();
    }
}

// Example
ExtendedZip::zipTree('/foo/bar', '/tmp/archive.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
```

Comment: Nice answer Giorgio! It gives better results  than Zip() on windows for tree structure. thanks

Answer (score 13):

I've edited [Alix Axel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89771/alix-axel)'s answer to take a third argrument, when setting this third argrument to `true` all the files will be added under the main directory rather than directly in the zip folder.

If the zip file exists the file will be deleted as well.

Example:

```
Zip('/path/to/maindirectory','/path/to/compressed.zip',true);
```

Third argrument `true` zip structure:

```
maindirectory
--- file 1
--- file 2
--- subdirectory 1
------ file 3
------ file 4
--- subdirectory 2
------ file 5
------ file 6
```

Third argrument `false` or missing zip structure:

```
file 1
file 2
subdirectory 1
--- file 3
--- file 4
subdirectory 2
--- file 5
--- file 6
```

Edited code:

```
function Zip($source, $destination, $include_dir = false)
{

    if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (file_exists($destination)) {
        unlink ($destination);
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
        return false;
    }
    $source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));

    if (is_dir($source) === true)
    {

        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        if ($include_dir) {

            $arr = explode("/",$source);
            $maindir = $arr[count($arr)- 1];

            $source = "";
            for ($i=0; $i < count($arr) - 1; $i++) { 
                $source .= '/' . $arr[$i];
            }

            $source = substr($source, 1);

            $zip->addEmptyDir($maindir);

        }

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);

            // Ignore "." and ".." folders
            if( in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/')+1), array('.', '..')) )
                continue;

            $file = realpath($file);

            if (is_dir($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
            }
            else if (is_file($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
            }
        }
    }
    else if (is_file($source) === true)
    {
        $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
    }

    return $zip->close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I needed to include the main directory in my situation.

Comment: you function is not working only main (root) directory is adding and nothing

Comment: I know this was answered a long ago. Is it possible to have a custom name for 'maindirectory' instead of the original name.

Comment: @VaibhavSidapara Believe that should be possible by changing `$maindir` to the preferred name.

Comment: Great answer, helped me alot. I did add a fourth argument to this function to include exclusions. I will add the final code as another answer to this question.

Answer (score 4):

USAGE:  **thisfile.php?dir=./path/to/folder** (After zipping, it starts **download** too:)

```
<?php
$exclude_some_files=
array(
        'mainfolder/folder1/filename.php',
        'mainfolder/folder5/otherfile.php'
);

//***************built from https://gist.github.com/ninadsp/6098467 ******
class ModifiedFlxZipArchive extends ZipArchive {
    public function addDirDoo($location, $name , $prohib_filenames=false) {
        if (!file_exists($location)) {  die("maybe file/folder path incorrect");}

        $this->addEmptyDir($name);
        $name .= '/';
        $location.= '/';
        $dir = opendir ($location);   // Read all Files in Dir

        while ($file = readdir($dir)){
            if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
            if (!in_array($name.$file,$prohib_filenames)){
                if (filetype( $location . $file) == 'dir'){
                    $this->addDirDoo($location . $file, $name . $file,$prohib_filenames );
                }
                else {
                    $this->addFile($location . $file, $name . $file);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function downld($zip_name){
        ob_get_clean();
        header("Pragma: public");   header("Expires: 0");   header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private", false);    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($zip_name) . ";" );
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zip_name));
        readfile($zip_name);
    }
}

//set memory limits
set_time_limit(3000);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);
ini_set('memory_limit','100M');
$new_zip_filename='down_zip_file_'.rand(1,1000000).'.zip';  
// Download action
if (isset($_GET['dir']))    {
    $za = new ModifiedFlxZipArchive;
    //create an archive
    if  ($za->open($new_zip_filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)) {
        $za->addDirDoo($_GET['dir'], basename($_GET['dir']), $exclude_some_files); $za->close();
    }else {die('cantttt');}

if (isset($_GET['dir']))    {
    $za = new ModifiedFlxZipArchive;
    //create an archive
    if  ($za->open($new_zip_filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)) {
        $za->addDirDoo($_GET['dir'], basename($_GET['dir']), $exclude_some_files); $za->close();
    }else {die('cantttt');}

    //download archive
    //on the same execution,this made problems in some hostings, so better redirect
    //$za -> downld($new_zip_filename);
    header("location:?fildown=".$new_zip_filename); exit;
}   
if (isset($_GET['fildown'])){
    $za = new ModifiedFlxZipArchive;
    $za -> downld($_GET['fildown']);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [this link](http://www.sajithmr.com/php-zipping-algorith/) <-- MORE SOURCE CODE HERE

```
/** Include the Pear Library for Zip */
include ('Archive/Zip.php');

/** Create a Zipping Object...
* Name of zip file to be created..
* You can specify the path too */
$obj = new Archive_Zip('test.zip');
/**
* create a file array of Files to be Added in Zip
*/
$files = array('black.gif',
'blue.gif',
);

/**
* creating zip file..if success do something else do something...
* if Error in file creation ..it is either due to permission problem (Solution: give 777 to that folder)
* Or Corruption of File Problem..
*/

if ($obj->create($files)) {
// echo 'Created successfully!';
} else {
//echo 'Error in file creation';
}

?>; // We'll be outputting a ZIP
header('Content-type: application/zip');

// It will be called test.zip
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.zip"');

//read a file and send
readfile('test.zip');
?>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here Is my code For Zip the folders and its sub folders and its files and make it downloadable in zip Format

```
function zip()
 {
$source='path/folder'// Path To the folder;
$destination='path/folder/abc.zip'// Path to the file and file name ; 
$include_dir = false;
$archive = 'abc.zip'// File Name ;

if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
    return false;
}

if (file_exists($destination)) {
    unlink ($destination);
}

$zip = new ZipArchive;

if (!$zip->open($archive, ZipArchive::CREATE)) {
    return false;
}
$source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));
if (is_dir($source) === true)
{

    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    if ($include_dir) {

        $arr = explode("/",$source);
        $maindir = $arr[count($arr)- 1];

        $source = "";
        for ($i=0; $i < count($arr) - 1; $i++) { 
            $source .= '/' . $arr[$i];
        }

        $source = substr($source, 1);

        $zip->addEmptyDir($maindir);

    }

    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);

        // Ignore "." and ".." folders
        if( in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/')+1), array('.', '..')) )
            continue;

        $file = realpath($file);

        if (is_dir($file) === true)
        {
            $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
        }
        else if (is_file($file) === true)
        {
            $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
        }
    }
}
else if (is_file($source) === true)
{
    $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$archive);
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($archive));
readfile($archive);
unlink($archive);
}
```

If Any Issue With the Code Let Me know.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to run this Zip function in Mac OSX

so I would always zip that annoying .DS_Store.

I adapted https://stackoverflow.com/users/2019515/user2019515 by including additionalIgnore files.

```
function zipIt($source, $destination, $include_dir = false, $additionalIgnoreFiles = array())
{
    // Ignore "." and ".." folders by default
    $defaultIgnoreFiles = array('.', '..');

    // include more files to ignore
    $ignoreFiles = array_merge($defaultIgnoreFiles, $additionalIgnoreFiles);

    if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (file_exists($destination)) {
        unlink ($destination);
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
        return false;
        }
    $source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));

    if (is_dir($source) === true)
    {

        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        if ($include_dir) {

            $arr = explode("/",$source);
            $maindir = $arr[count($arr)- 1];

            $source = "";
            for ($i=0; $i < count($arr) - 1; $i++) { 
                $source .= '/' . $arr[$i];
            }

            $source = substr($source, 1);

            $zip->addEmptyDir($maindir);

        }

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);

            // purposely ignore files that are irrelevant
            if( in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/')+1), $ignoreFiles) )
                continue;

            $file = realpath($file);

            if (is_dir($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
            }
            else if (is_file($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
            }
        }
    }
    else if (is_file($source) === true)
    {
        $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
    }

    return $zip->close();
}
```

SO to ignore the .DS_Store from zip, you run

zipIt('/path/to/folder', '/path/to/compressed.zip', false, array('.DS_Store'));

Answer (score 0):

Great solution but for my Windows I need make a modifications. Below the modify code

```
function Zip($source, $destination){

if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
    return false;
}

$zip = new ZipArchive();
if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
    return false;
}

$source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));

if (is_dir($source) === true)
{
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);

        // Ignore "." and ".." folders
        if( in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/')+1), array('.', '..')) )
            continue;

        if (is_dir($file) === true)
        {
            $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file));
        }
        else if (is_file($file) === true)
        {

            $str1 = str_replace($source . '/', '', '/'.$file);
            $zip->addFromString($str1, file_get_contents($file));

        }
    }
}
else if (is_file($source) === true)
{
    $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
}

return $zip->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for both windows and linux.

```
function Zip($source, $destination)
{
if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
    return false;
}

$zip = new ZipArchive();
if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
    return false;
}

if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
    DEFINE('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); //for windows
} else {
    DEFINE('DS', '/'); //for linux
}


$source = str_replace('\\', DS, realpath($source));

if (is_dir($source) === true)
{
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    echo $source;
    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        $file = str_replace('\\',DS, $file);
        // Ignore "." and ".." folders
        if( in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, DS)+1), array('.', '..')) )
            continue;

        $file = realpath($file);

        if (is_dir($file) === true)
        {
            $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . DS, '', $file . DS));
        }
        else if (is_file($file) === true)
        {
            $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . DS, '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
        }
        echo $source;
    }
}
else if (is_file($source) === true)
{
    $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
}

return $zip->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version base on Alix's, works on Windows and hopefully on *nix too:

```
function addFolderToZip($source, $destination, $flags = ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE)
{
    $source = realpath($source);
    $destination = realpath($destination);

    if (!file_exists($source)) {
        die("file does not exist: " . $source);
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if (!$zip->open($destination, $flags )) {
        die("Cannot open zip archive: " . $destination);
    }

    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    $sourceWithSeparator = $source . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        // Ignore "." and ".." folders
        if(in_array(substr($file,strrpos($file, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)+1),array('.', '..')))
            continue;

        if (is_dir($file) === true)
        {
            $zip->addEmptyDir(
                str_replace($sourceWithSeparator, '', $file . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR));
        }
        else if (is_file($file) === true)
        {
            $zip->addFile($file, str_replace($sourceWithSeparator, '', $file));
        }
    }

    return $zip->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple, easy to read, recursive function that works very well:

```
function zip_r($from, $zip, $base=false) {
    if (!file_exists($from) OR !extension_loaded('zip')) {return false;}
    if (!$base) {$base = $from;}
    $base = trim($base, '/');
    $zip->addEmptyDir($base);
    $dir = opendir($from);
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
        if ($file == '.' OR $file == '..') {continue;}

        if (is_dir($from . '/' . $file)) {
            zip_r($from . '/' . $file, $zip, $base . '/' . $file);
        } else {
            $zip->addFile($from . '/' . $file, $base . '/' . $file);
        }
    }
    return $zip;
}
$from = "/path/to/folder";
$base = "basezipfolder";
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('zipfile.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
$zip = zip_r($from, $zip, $base);
$zip->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Following @user2019515 answer, I needed to handle exclusions to my archive. here is the resulting function with an example.

Zip Function :

```
function Zip($source, $destination, $include_dir = false, $exclusions = false){
    // Remove existing archive
    if (file_exists($destination)) {
        unlink ($destination);
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
        return false;
    }
    $source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));
    if (is_dir($source) === true){
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
        if ($include_dir) {
            $arr = explode("/",$source);
            $maindir = $arr[count($arr)- 1];
            $source = "";
            for ($i=0; $i < count($arr) - 1; $i++) {
                $source .= '/' . $arr[$i];
            }
            $source = substr($source, 1);
            $zip->addEmptyDir($maindir);
        }
        foreach ($files as $file){
            // Ignore "." and ".." folders
            $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);
            if(in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/')+1), array('.', '..'))){
                continue;
            }

            // Add Exclusion
            if(($exclusions)&&(is_array($exclusions))){
                if(in_array(str_replace($source.'/', '', $file), $exclusions)){
                    continue;
                }
            }

            $file = realpath($file);
            if (is_dir($file) === true){
                $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
            } elseif (is_file($file) === true){
                $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
            }
        }
    } elseif (is_file($source) === true){
        $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
    }
    return $zip->close();
}
```

How to use it :

```
function backup(){
    $backup = 'tmp/backup-'.$this->site['version'].'.zip';
    $exclusions = [];
    // Excluding an entire directory
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('tmp/'), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    foreach ($files as $file){
        array_push($exclusions,$file);
    }
    // Excluding a file
    array_push($exclusions,'config/config.php');
    // Excluding the backup file
    array_push($exclusions,$backup);
    $this->Zip('.',$backup, false, $exclusions);
}
```