# PHP Zip method - need advice

Tags: php

http://pastebin.com/AreCLL5W

Could anyone help me with this, I've been trying all day to get a file to compress for email but for some reason it's failing to compress ? I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong (it's probably staring me in the face)

Comment: yet another question with "I have a problem" without saying which is the problem/error lol :)

Comment: It's just not producing a file, I have a feeling it's to do with my variable usage. I have with no variable usage (e.g "test.zip") and it works fine ?

Comment: That pastebin is pretty much useless as it does not show the code you are using to zip the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having problems with that function, i would suggest the function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334613/how-to-recursively-zip-a-directory-in-php/1334949#1334949).

I personally have used that function before and it works like a dream and is easy to understand.

It works for both files and folders.

Comment: From the above linked answer, the original asker's problem might be because they do not have the zip extension installed. Make sure that "if (extension_loaded('zip') === true)" is true.

Comment: The problem was actually down to incorrect capture of the download code.