# exec zip root path

Tags: php, zip, exec, dir

Im having some problems zipping a directory.
The following line will do the trick but it also includes the root directory.

```
exec('zip -r '.$tmp_zip.' '.$filename_no_ext.'/rss-ticker/*');
```

So I only want to zip everything in the dir rss-ticker
How to fix this?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have an overwhelming reason not to (like a desire to cause yourself much pain and headache), you really should be using the [ZipArchive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) toolkit. There is an example of how at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334613/how-to-recursively-zip-a-directory-in-php).

As to getting zip to work with `exec`, I noticed two points:

1. you will definitely need the `$filename_no_ext` variable in there. If you just have it be a `.`. Right now, because you're starting `rss-ticker` with `/`, it is assuming that the folder is at the root of the file-system. I don't think you want that.
2. You do not need the trailing `*` to get the command line `zip` function to work.

Answer (score 1):

What zip program are you using? `tar` works in the way that you want it to above, then you can `gzip` it.

Alternatively, [`chdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) to the directory you want to zip, and specify your path as `*` - that should only get the files in the current working directory.

If you can't get it to work in the way you want to (or even if you can) try the [ZIP Extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) or [this 3rd party library](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip) - doing it in pure PHP will make your code more portable.