# Yii2 generate zip file and download- In YII2.0

Tags: php, yii2, zip, yii2-advanced-app, php-ziparchive

I have a situation, I have list of user data, in that data details, i have stored a file also.
Now i want to download all the file of users in zip file, when a user click on a button like DOWNLOAD.

i have written a action in controller where im fetching the file to be downloaded, but im unable to write code for making zip finle and download it.
Below is my code in controller.

```
public function actionMain($jid)
{
     $values = UserRequest::find()->where(['sender_code'=>$jid,'status'=>1])->all();
       $i=1; foreach($values as $data) { 
             $users = Users::find()->where(['access_code'=>$data->reciever_code])->one();
             $file_names[]= $users->attach_cv;
         }
 }
```

This is working fine. in $file_name im fetching all the file's, But i want to download this files in a zip foder.

Please help me to solve this issue

The link provided is in core php and easily implemented in that. But how about doing the same in framework. Because i have array of file name in action. As you can see above. DO i need to write the code for generating .ZIP in the same action or any other action.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ZIP all files in directory and download .zip generated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708562/zip-all-files-in-directory-and-download-zip-generated)

Comment: No tat solution is in core php. I need to do in Yii2.0 framework.

Comment: Please explain, in the answer itself, why you cannot use . Also, if the whole point is generating a ZIP file from multiple data files, you should probably shorten your question and drop all the irrelevant details - unless you want to bypass the individual file generation altogether, in which case make _that_ clear instead.

Comment: I want to generate and download the file at the same time. so tats where im facing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) as specified in the comment by [SiZE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3041129/size).
That way you initiate the zipping process before you start the download.

File creation:

```
/**
 * Generate zip file for upload
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
private function createZip($files)
{
    $file = 'full_path_to_file/your_file_name.zip';

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if ($zip->open($file, ZipArchive::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
        throw new \Exception('Cannot create a zip file');
    }

    foreach($files as $file){
        $zip->addFile($file[file_name], $file[local_name]);
    }

    $zip->close();

}
```

And then you can return the zip file path for download in your action

Comment: can you please elaborate little bit. Im new to this.