# Zipping all files and folders without php exec

Tags: php, backup, exec

I am looking to a way to zip all my files and folders for a project i am working on i have everything working with the code below on my install.

```
exec('tar -czf backup.tar root/');
```

But on the clients shared hosting we get the error.

```
Warning: exec() has been disabled for security reasons in
```

Can anyone suggest the best way to do this without exec function???

Would really help thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating .zip file : PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540339/creating-zip-file-php)

Comment: There are several implementations of compression algorithms in various php extensions and pear packages. Use them.