# how to zip all ftp files using php

Tags: php, zip

I have files in a remote location that I grab through ftp, and I want to zip all files and directory into a zip using php.

I've used this, but it does not work. Does anyone know how to zip files?

The below code doesn't work at all.

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 5000);

class xZip {
    public function __construct() {}
    private function _rglobRead($source, &$array = array()) {
        if (!$source || trim($source) == "") {
            $source = ".";
        }
        foreach ((array) glob($source . "/*/") as $key => $value) {
            $this->_rglobRead(str_replace("//", "/", $value), $array);
        }

        foreach ((array) glob($source . "*.*") as $key => $value) {
            $array[] = str_replace("//", "/", $value);
        }
    }
    private function _zip($array, $part, $destination) {
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        @mkdir($destination, 0777, true);

        if ($zip->open(str_replace("//", "/", "{$destination}/partz{$part}.zip"), ZipArchive::CREATE)) {
            foreach ((array) $array as $key => $value) {
                $zip->addFile($value, str_replace(array("../", "./"), NULL, $value));
            }
            $zip->close();
        }
    }
    public function zip($limit = 50000, $source = NULL, $destination = "./") {
        if (!$destination || trim($destination) == "") {
            $destination = "./";
        }

        $this->_rglobRead($source, $input);
        $maxinput = count($input);
        $splitinto = (($maxinput / $limit) > round($maxinput / $limit, 0)) ? round($maxinput / $limit, 0) + 1 : round($maxinput / $limit, 0);

        for($i = 0; $i < $splitinto; $i ++) {
            $this->_zip(array_slice($input, ($i * $limit), $limit, true), $i, $destination);
        }

        unset($input);
        return;
    }
    public function unzip($source, $destination) {
        @mkdir($destination, 0777, true);

        foreach ((array) glob($source . "/*.zip") as $key => $value) {
            $zip = new ZipArchive;
            if ($zip->open(str_replace("//", "/", $value)) === true) {
                $zip->extractTo($destination);
                $zip->close();
            }
        }
    }

    public function __destruct() {}
}

$zip = new xZip;
$zip->zip(50000, "auto/", "c/");
//$zip->unzip("images_zip/", "images/");
?>
```

regards 
dev

Comment: When you said "it worked", what changed? Are you getting any error messages? Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` towards the top of the script and see if anything echo's out.

Comment: i says uploaded but i was not able to see files in that folder

Comment: When you run the script, it should show some text such as `Archive created successfully with $numFiles files.`. What are you seeing when you run the script?

Comment: it says Archive created successfully with $numFiles files.

Comment: Then you're lying, because it should never say `$numFiles`.

Comment: no i am getting  like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on Linux and not limited by php's safe_mode (use phpinfo() to find out) then you could simply use exec() to run the zip command from a shell like:

**Method 1:-**

```
<?php
exec("zip -R public_html.zip /home/username/public_html",$output);
?>
```

**Method 2:-**

```
<?php 

$archive = "xyz.zip";
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
exec( "zip -r $archive $directory");

 ?>
```

For Local systems you can use this code for zip the specific folders.

```
<?php

function Zip($source, $destination)
{

echo "called function";
    if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
        return false;
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
        return false;
    }

    $source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));

    if (is_dir($source) === true)
    {
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);

            // Ignore "." and ".." folders
            if( in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/')+1), array('.', '..')) )
                continue;

            $file = realpath($file);

            if (is_dir($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
            }
            else if (is_file($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
            }
        }
    }
    else if (is_file($source) === true)
    {
        $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
    }

    return $zip->close();
}

Zip('D:/tmp','D:/tmp/compressed.zip',true);


?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: first i want to test with xampp can you give for that

Comment: what xampp?,xampp is support to both windows and linux xyxtems,please check in your server, i think it's work

Comment: what error you got on run the above code(method1 ,method 2)

Comment: i updated code please check but in this files are zipping but not all files some files are zipping

Comment: I have updated my answer,that code is working perfectly in my local system,you can use it.

Comment: have you tested that above code? let me know result success or fail?

Comment: i got another code it works! your code also works thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try with below links ,i think this links are reached your requirement.

[Creating .zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540339/creating-zip-file-php)

and another one

http://runnable.com/UnF5GrIOBM91AAAR/create-a-zip-archive-using-php

Comment: not working can you give me another code i have ftp files i want to zip all files in one zip

Comment: give me path  of your ftp files then automatically zip all files as one.

Comment: /public_html/ this is the root directory

Comment: @deb i have given one answer can you check and let me know.