# ZipArchive::CREATE is not creating a zip file and returning true

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

Hello i am just creating a zip file using php but the file not being created however it is return **boolean true** i dont know whats problem going on. before created what did i do

1. i installed php zip in my Ubuntu using `sudo apt-get install php-zip` and after installation i restarted my apache server.
2. create a zip.php file file and write this code

`$zip = new ZipArchive;
//var_dump($zip->open('test.zip',ZipArchive::CREATE));
$f = $zip->open('zip/myzip.zip',ZipArchive::CREATE);
var_dump($f);`

this code return true but file not being created

3. no any file permission issue i already given it to my directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating .zip file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540339/creating-zip-file)

Comment: @AlexSlipknot i did not get your point. there is no zip file in zip folder.

Comment: $zip->addFile("file_path","file_name");

Comment: zip file is the file :) not the folder. It contain files and structure. Follow provided link to get what you should do to create zip-archive

Answer (score 2):

Empty Zip can not be created, You have to select some files to create a zip file. Try below code

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "test.zip";

if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}
$zip->addFile("a.jpg","b.jpg");
$zip->close();
```

replace 'a.jpg', 'b.jpg' from your files.

Comment: thank you dear it is working code but i have still confusion that if a zip file not created till now then how can it returns true.