# How to Add PHP to File Inside ZIP with Automated Script

Tags: php, automation

I am trying to figure out the best method to automate adding a single includes line to the top of a PHP file within a ZIP without having to manually unzip the archive, open file, paste code and then recompress. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, Everything possible. Unzip file with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889025/unzip-a-file-with-php , then write file as per your requirement then again zip it using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540339/creating-zip-file

Comment: How do you add a line to the top of a php file? What PHP command is there for that?