# pclzip to backup two directories

Tags: php, zip

Does anyone have experience with [PclZip](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/)? I want to create a backup of two folders and all their contents recursively, but I only found on their website [FAQ](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/faq) a way that seems to do it for the entire working directory, but not for two specific directories. Furthermore, does anyone have experience with, aside from [php zip](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) (not installed on my host), a php zipping program that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class

Here is a very good example how to accomplish exactly what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1334949/893130

Comment: how can one use this code to iterate through two directories and have them in the same zip? I just want to backup my images folder i.e. `/images/upload/` and `/cms/images/users/`