# Zip file created by PHP contains empty files with same name as directory when opened with Windows

Tags: php, windows, zip

I have a PHP script that zips a directory (and all its sub-directories and files) using code found I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334613/how-to-recursively-zip-a-directory-in-php). I modified the code to use `$zip->addFile()` instead of `$zip->addFromString` and `file_get_contents` because I'm zipping large directories (hundreds of MB) and those methods quickly max out my php memory limit (set at 128M). My modified code is:

```
function Zip($source, $destination)
{
    if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
        return false;
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE)) {
        return false;
    }

    $source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));

    if (is_dir($source) === true)
    {
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        foreach ($files as $file){
            $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);

            // Ignore "." and ".." folders
            if( in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/')+1), array('.', '..')) )
                continue;

            $file = realpath($file);

            if (is_dir($file) === true){
                $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
            }else if (is_file($file) === true){
                $zip->addFile($file, str_replace($source . '/', '', $file);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (is_file($source) === true){
        $zip->addFile($source, basename($source));
    }

    return $zip->close();
}
```

This code does an admirable job of zipping the file. I use some HTTP headers to redirect the browser to download the zip file; that also works well. The problem I'm experiencing doesn't appear until I go to unzip the downloaded .zip file. On Linux and OS X, the file downloads and unzips normally; no abnormalities. However, when I attempt to unzip these .zip files in Windows Vista, there are extra files in the zip file.

For example, if I zipped a directory with the structure

```
- topDir (directory)
    - subDir (directory)
        - pic.jpg (file)
```

Windows shows this structure inside the zip file:

```
- topDir (directory)
- topDir (file, size = 0 bytes)
    - subDir (directory)
    - subDir (file, size = 0 bytes)
        - pic.jpg (file)
```

I don't understand where these phantom files are coming from. They wouldn't be an issue, but Windows gets confused when it tries to unzip the thing and finds a file and directory with the same name. Any thoughts on where they come from? I've only tried Windows' default zipping application; it may be that 7zip can handle the file.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I believe to are seeing the result of OS X's resource forks when you extract in Windows. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_fork for more.