# Recursive Zip directory in PHP Windows?

Tags: php, recursion

I'm using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334613/how-to-recursively-zip-a-directory-in-php) to zip a folder

```
 D:\VIRTUAL\consuladoperurio.com.br\WWW\siscons\test\wordtemplatedownload\pasta
```

into test.zip. The folder "pasta" has the follow tree

```
pasta
    subfolder
        styles.xml
```

When I run the code

```
$wordtemplatedownloadpath ="D:\\VIRTUAL\\consuladoperurio.com.br\\WWW\\siscons\\test\\wordtemplatedownload\\"
Zip($wordtemplatedownloadpath."pasta", $wordtemplatedownloadpath."test.zip");
```

and then extract test.zip I get the folder and file

[image]
respectively. When I need the first tree.

I'm trying to replace '/' to '\' but don't work.
How I will be able to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

I will concentrate on your last question "I'm trying to replace '/' to '\' but don't work. How I will be able to solve that?" as at the moment it is unclear what you are asking about.

But if you are having problems specifying a path to your directory try to use the constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR within your path definition

Example

> $wordtemplatedownloadpath ="D:" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "VIRTUAL" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "consuladoperurio.com.br" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "WWW" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "siscons" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "test" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "wordtemplatedownload" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ;

Please let me know if this fixes your problem