# Create ODT file using ZipArchive

Tags: php

I'm trying to create odt file of the files:

[image]

using [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php). How I will be able to reproduce this linux command

```
 zip -r ../zip.odt mimetype *
```

using ZipArchive in php in Windows?

- I'm looking for in [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334613/how-to-recursively-zip-a-directory-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Use the PHP [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) command to run arbitrary code.

```
exec("zip -r ../zip.odt mimetype *");
```

Comment: OP (yes, I see that is you) specifically asked for "Linux command". If you are on Windows and have the ZipArchive extension installed, then try some of the [ZipArchive examples](http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php). I think that the first example is relevant for your case. Let use know how it went.

Comment: @dotancochen yes I'm using this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334613/how-to-recursively-zip-a-directory-in-php but I get a error input/general error. Then, I want zip directly using zip in line command.

Comment: Then I recommend either one of two things: addressing the error that you are receiving or using a server OS for your webserver. I know that Windows is a popular desktop OS, but as a professional I cringed when you added "on Windows" to the question. You really don't want to do that :) Post a new question with the error that you are receiving and let's address that.

Comment: I had write a that question but I don't get replies. Here a link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26444303/create-odt-file-using-zip-php-general-input-output-error

Comment: I've commented over there. That question is only 18 hours old, you will find that sometimes questions take days or weeks before somebody knowledgeable comes along.