# Creating a zip archive in php

Tags: php, zip

I found this topic for creating a zip file froma folder: [How to [recursively] Zip a directory in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334613/how-to-recursively-zip-a-directory-in-php). 
Alix Axel's solution seems to work, but I always get the cull path of the folder inside the archive. I have tried to change all the '/'-s to '\'-s, but still, the problem exists. 
The code calling the function is the following:

```
    $exportdirname = "userpackages\\" . $_POST['exportname'] . '_' . $_SESSION['maps_username'];
    Zip($exportdirname . "\\", $exportdirname . '.zip');
```

What could possibly be the problem?