# Adding all subdirectories to a zip archive

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

In this case I am trying to add all files and subdirectories to my zip file.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('wordpress.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);

// Adding all files
foreach (glob(CLIENT_PATH . "/*.*") as $file) {
    $filename = substr($file, strrpos($file, '/') + 1);
    echo $filename . '<br>';
   $zip->addFile($file, 'wordpress/wp-content/themes/' . $title . '/' . $filename);
}

// Adding all subdirectories
$directories = glob(CLIENT_PATH . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
foreach (glob(CLIENT_PATH . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
    $zip->addEmptyDir('wordpress/wp-content/themes/' . $title . '/' . $dir);
}

$zip->close();
```

Adding all files works perfectly well but adding all subdirectories won't work as expected.

This is how my unzipped file looks:

[image]

The subdirectory of my main directory is called `assets` and it also includes some more subdirectories and they also have some subdirectories. But as you see in the image above, `assets` includes just nothing. And also, I don't understand why it starts with home/pomcanys/ etc. instead of `assets`.

How can I fix this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why you do `GLOB_ONLYDIR`?

Comment: Your code here shows only how do add files and empty folders in/from the current folder. There is no code that recursivey adds sub files/folders. Also you are doing `addEmptyDir` and `addFile` only. What its going on here?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions you are right. I just noticed that my code sucks. Please just ignore the part "adding all subdirectories" of my code. I am just looking for something like "`addDir()`" to add directories just the way I have added files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1334949/4916265

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to \[recursively\] Zip a directory in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334613/how-to-recursively-zip-a-directory-in-php)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions this would work but it is not adding the files to the specific sub directory that I want: wp_content/themes/theme_name

Comment: What should i do from here? What should i say know? This was just a link where it is explained how to do this. Get the needed information from there an update your code and test.

Answer (score 0):

To automatically include files from the sub-directories [use the -r parameter](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/zip.htm) for recursiveness:

```
zip -r foo.zip *
```