# Zip Folder and Download it in Joomla Backend

Tags: php, joomla, zip, php-ziparchive

I am trying to add an option in a custom Joomla 3.9 component to zip some pdfs and download them from the backend. I used [this tutorial](https://makitweb.com/how-to-create-and-download-a-zip-file-with-php/).
I edited the file defalt.php inside /administrator/components/com_mycomponent/views/item/tmpl/ and added the following:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['create'])){
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = JPATH_ROOT . '/myfolder/myzipfile.zip';
if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}
$dir = JPATH_ROOT . '/myfolder/';
// Create zip
createZip($zip,$dir);
$zip->close();
}

// Create zip
function createZip($zip,$dir){
if (is_dir($dir)){
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){              
            // If file
            if (is_file($dir.$file)) {
                if($file != '' && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){                       
                    $zip->addFile($dir.$file);
                }
            }else{
                // If directory
                if(is_dir($dir.$file) ){
                    if($file != '' && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){
                        // Add empty directory
                        $zip->addEmptyDir($dir.$file);
                        $folder = $dir.$file.'/';                          
                        // Read data of the folder
                        createZip($zip,$folder);
                    }
                }      
            }         
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
}

//Download Created Zip file
if(isset($_POST['download'])){   
$filename = JPATH_ROOT . '/myfolder/myzipfile.zip';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
    flush();
    readfile($filename);
    // delete file
    unlink($filename);
}
}
?>
```

The zip file is created in the correct location with the correct/expected size but it is either corrupt or empty.

I tried solutions found here in other posts but nothing worked.

**Update:** I opened the zipped file with 7-zip and found it contains the drive letter where xampp is installed. The myzipfile.zip and all the compressed files were under: G:/xampp/localhost/myjoomlasite/myfolder

Clicking on myzipfile.zip led me in the same path like a loop.
Replacing JPATH_ROOT with JPATH_SITE gave the same results.

I hope someone can shed a light on what happened here.

Comment: When you are seeking support while doing Joomla development, you have a question that should be posted on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

With `$zip->addFile($filename)` you're adding the file with the full path to the zip archive. I guess having relative paths is your goal? So, you would need to cut the paths and use `$zip->addFile($filename, $localFileName)`. There might be much better solutions, the easiest way is to simply remove the base path from `$filename` to get `$localFileName`.

You could also use the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` to loop through your files and directories.

Maybe this link helps, too
[How to [recursively] Zip a directory in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334613/how-to-recursively-zip-a-directory-in-php)